# Upload multiple pdf files to server using excel template?

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext, pdf-reader, pdfstamper

I have list of pdf file url in excel template Now i want to upload all files from my local pc to server just by browsing the excel file and click to upload.

I have achieved this task by using iTextSharp Library pdfreader and pdfstamper class, but what problem is, i need to read all files by using pdfreader.

Case may come, when some of **pdf files are encrypted**, So  i can not able to read that file using pdfreader of itextsharp and not be able to upload the same.

**Is it possible that without reading the pdf file i can just dumped it to server just like what Fileupload.Saveas method does????**